# How to get Paragraph Ids of a onenote created using graph api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, microsoft-graph-onenote

I have created a OneNote page using graph api, now I want to retrieve the links to the paragraphs in the OneNote to update in a separate document.
I tried the content url but it doesn't return anything. Can someone suggest what would be the endpoint to get the paragraph link?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no such API to get a paragraph link to a OneNote page.Being said that, you can consider filing [user voice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) for your specific ask so that it could be considered for future implementation.

Refer to the documentation here for all [Notes API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onenote-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) provided by Graph.